# N Identical Balls numbered through 1 to n

Tags: probability

A box contains n identical balls numbered 1 through n. Suppose k balls are drawn in succession.

What is probability that m is largest number drawn ?

What is the probability that the largest number drawn is less than or equal to m ?

Comment: Are the balls drawn with replacement, or without?

Comment: Nothing is given.

Comment: I guess it is without replacement!

Comment: Can we consider both ways and then solve the problem ?

Comment: Hint: the second problem is easier than the first.

Comment: @David can you share the approach ? I will try to do it myself ?

Comment: Rather can anyone please explain taking real values  ?

Comment: The largest number drawn is less than or equal to $m$ if and only if the numbers ... are never drawn.  (Can you fill in the dots?)

Comment: The second question can be solved using David's hint, 
and a proof of the first question can be found [here](http://www.algebra.com/algebra/homework/Probability-and-statistics/Probability-and-statistics.faq.question.570976.html)

Comment: @David I am really new to this stuff . I am really grateful for your help. But can you please elaborate ? Also please tell if I am getting the scenario correct ? Consider 10 balls numbered from 1 to 10. We draw 3 balls. Now we want the probability that m is the largest number drawn? The largest number from the set is 10. Is this correct ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will assume that balls are drawn without replacement.  Obviously the probability is zero if $k>m$.  Otherwise...

The largest number drawn is less than or equal to $m$ if and only if balls $m+1,\ldots,n$ are never drawn, that is, all $k$ draws come from $\{1,2,\ldots,m\}$.  The probability is
$$p_{m,n}=\frac{P(m,k)}{P(n,k)}=\frac mn\frac{m-1}{n-1}\cdots\frac{m-(k-1)}{n-(k-1)}\ .$$

The largest number drawn is equal to $m$ if and only if it is less than or equal to $m$, and **not** less than or equal to $m-1$.  The probability is
$$p_{m,n}-p_{m-1,n}\ .$$
Using factorial expressions for permutation numbers, this can be simplified to
$$\eqalign{p_{m,n}-p_{m-1,n}
  &=\frac{m!}{(m-k)!}-\frac{m-1!}{(m-k-1)!}\cr
  &=\frac{(m-1)!}{(m-k)!}(m-(m-k))\cr
  &=k\frac{(m-1)!}{(m-k)!}\ .\cr}$$

Answer (score 0):

The total space is to draw $k$ balls from $\{1,...,N\}$.   How many ways can we do this?

- For $(1)$ the favoured event is to draw ball $\#m$, and *how many* balls from $\{1,..., m-1\}$, and *how many* from $\{m+1,...,N\}$ so that the largest ball will then be $\#m$.   How many ways can we do this?
- For $(2)$ the favoured event is to draw *how many* balls from $\{1, ..., m\}$ and *how many* from $\{m+1,...,N\}$; so that the largest ball will then be no greater than $\#m$.   How many ways can we do this?

We assert that this is a set of equally probable outcomes.   To obtain the probabilities we divide and calculate.

Comment: Hey Graham Thanks for making it easier to understand. Since the it is a set of equally probable outcomes for (1) we will have (1/N) *(choose k-1 balls from m -1 ) right ?

Comment: For(2) we will draw 0 from  {m+1,....,N} and k balls from  {0....m } right  ?

Comment: @Graham Kemp In your first bullet-point, why is it ${0,...,m-1}$?  Is it because ball $m$ falls between $0,..,m-1$ and $m+1,...,N$?

Comment: It was $0$ because the set in the question was somehow not the set in the answer.