# Need further explanation for this problem

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I have recently asked this problem:
[What is the probability that $m$ is the largest number drawn?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2975112/what-is-the-probability-that-m-is-the-largest-number-drawn?noredirect=1#comment6140630_2975112)

I don't understand how one arrive at the questions posted by lulu and greedoid. 
I guess I don't understand what the problem asks for.

Could you provide a fuller explanation to these answers?

Comment: As a general point, to address a comment to a user, use "@".  As in @JamesWarthington.  Without that, nobody sees your comment unless they happen to revisit that page.  I'll post a more detailed answer to your original post.

Comment: In that case, you should edit the previous post to clarify what it is you're asking (or allow for more time for a detailed response).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps working on a special case will simplify it for you.

Assume you have the 10 balls, numbered 1 to 10.  You'll choose 3 balls at random (without replacement).  What is the probability that the highest number among the balls you picked is 7.

You have $10 \choose 3$ ways of picking any 3 balls.  How many possible draws if you restrict the max to 7?  That is $7 \choose 3$. However, this doesn't mean, the max will be 7 (you can very well pick balls (1,2,3) all less than 7).  Now, the trick is writing $P(\max=7)==P(\max \le 7)-P(\max \le 6)$

For the values we have $P(\max = 7) = \frac{{7 \choose 3} - {6 \choose 3}}{10 \choose 3}=\frac{6 \choose 2}{10 \choose 3} = \frac18$

Try special cases for one ball draw, 10 ball draw and/or max=10 to get more intuition.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.